# Interactive string manipulation via javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, string

I have a webapp that must allow users to interactively manipulate strings (words, phrases and so on...)

Example:

given a `foobar` string, if the user clicks on `b` the string is split in two and a whitespace is added, resulting in `foo bar`.

I could put each single character inside a `span` element, but I fear this would be troublesome for long strings.

Any advice?

Comment: If you want to capture events on individual characters, you'll need to have each character in an individual element.

Comment: Textarea: `foobar` => **CLICK between o and b** => `foo bar`? Is that enough?

Comment: You may be interested in looking at [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com), which can put letters (or words) in `<span>` tags for you.

Comment: @polarblau this may be a good start.

Comment: Have a look at Rangy for cross-browser selections & ranges. http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghyff/) version using jQuery (not necessary) should pretty much do what you need if I understood you correctly:

```
// Given a textarea with the content
var text = $('textarea').text().split('');

$('textarea').click(function(){
    text.splice(this.selectionStart, 0, " ");
    this.value = text.join('');
});
```

It's a very simple and not cross browser enabled example, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good starting point. Also, thanks for the example :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be ok, but setup your event handler not on individual spans, but on the whole container and then see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern